# Add timezone to HAProxy logs

Tags: debian, configuration, timezone, haproxy

I have a HAProxy (2.2.9) running on an Debian 11 machine and I would like to add the timezone to the HAProxy logs like Apache has: `[25/Jul/2023:14:27:40 +0200]`.

I have found that I can use the [`log-format`](http://docs.haproxy.org/2.2/configuration.html#8.2.4) parameter in the configuration `defaults` settings. In combination with the [`ltime`](http://docs.haproxy.org/2.2/configuration.html#7.3.1-ltime) converter I have formatted the following: `[%[date,ltime(%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z)]]` which kind of works.

The problem I'm having right now is that it displays the time like this: `[25/Jul/2023:12:27:40 +0000]` Where the time is UTC and no timezone is set.

Taking a look at the servers time using `timedatectl` displays the following:

```
Local time: Tue 2023-07-25 14:37:12 CEST
           Universal time: Tue 2023-07-25 12:37:12 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2023-07-25 12:37:13
                Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Which to me looks like the timezone and time are set correctly.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Does 'apt install tzdata' help? This worked for me using the docker image https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/issues/217